# How to use the for re^itheta to prove this?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone please explain how to use the form $re^{i\theta}$ and de Moivre's to prove that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin n\theta}{2^n} = \frac{2^{N+1} \sin \theta + \sin N\theta - 2\sin(N + 1)\theta}{2^N(5 - 4\cos \theta)}.$$

Here's what i did:

$Img \sum_{n=1}^N (\frac{re^i\theta}{2})^n  = \frac{0.5e^i\theta - (1 - (0.5e^i\theta)^N)}{1-e^i\theta}$

i m stuck now

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics.StackExchange! To help others come up with an answer that helps, can you break the problem down into what you've tried, and which part you got stuck on?  Also, it may be beneficial to reformat the question into text instead of a picture so that others can copy/search on the problem statement.

Comment: Sorry for that. 

I've started with finding the Imaginary part of the sum of ((costheta + isintheta)/2)^n GEOMETRIC PROGRESSION... I've come to the part where : $(e^itheta -e^(N+1)theta)/(2^N)(2-e^itheta)$

How do i further solve this. I mean how do i get the imaginary part of the equation.

Comment: @AliNaqvi Edit your progress into the question.  Then to format your expression correctly type `$(e^{i \theta}-e^{(N+1)\theta})/(2^N)\ (2-e^{i\theta})$` or `$\dfrac{e^{i \theta}-e^{(N+1)\theta}}{2^N} (2-e^{i\theta})$`to get $(e^{i \theta}-e^{(N+1)\theta})/(2^N)\ (2-e^{i\theta})$ or $\dfrac{e^{i \theta}-e^{(N+1)\theta}}{2^N} (2-e^{i\theta})$, respectively.

Comment: Added. Pleas have a look